# Setting an automatic tick interval

Tags: python, matplotlib

When I draw a plot with pyplot, it automatically generates nice widely space tick marks and labels. Is there a simple way to adjust the spacing between the automatically generated marks? For example, in a plot where default tick positions are `[2,4,6]`, have ticks at positions `[2,3,4,5,6]`.

I know I can set the mark positions and labels with `xticks()` and `yticks()`, but I need to know the range of values first, and with different data, I'd need to adjust them manually.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a whole bunch of tick locators and formatters, depending on what you want to standardize. Here's an example of linearly spacing ticks, set up for comparison with the default:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame((np.random.random((2,30)).T),columns=['A','B'])
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1,2)
axs[0].scatter(df.A, df.B)
axs[0].set_title('Default y-locator')
from matplotlib.ticker import LinearLocator
axs[1].get_yaxis().set_major_locator(LinearLocator(numticks=12))
axs[1].set_title('12 evenly spaced y-ticks')
axs[1].scatter(df.A, df.B)
```

[image]
See, generally, http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html?highlight=fixedlocator#module-matplotlib.ticker and the example gallery.

Comment: Thanks, that's nearly exactly what I was after.. Any chance you could change the LinearLocator for a MultipleLocator in the example? Thanks for the link also (that's where I found the MultipleLocator ;)

Comment: For those new to matplotlib, `fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)` is a convenient way to get at the `Figure` and `Axis` objects associated with a plot. If you're working interactively, some like to use `from matplotlib.pyplot import *` (or `%pylab` in Ipython), in which case leave out the `plt.`.

Comment: thanks, @drevicko. I'll add that I do the full-specification style even for short scripts because I find it, in the long run, saves me confusion to be explicit about what object is doing what. (This is especially the case when pasting scripts together.)

Comment: and... have you not plopped the MultipleLocator into the example yourself? I made it to be experimentable.

Comment: yes.. and it does what I was after.. so.. it answers the specific question I was asking.. It doesn't really matter though, easy enough to go find it behind the link you gave, even if you're in a hurry (: